# Htaccess - URL amigável na raiz do site

Tags: php, htaccess

Como fazer URL amigável abrir na raiz.

Tenho o arquivo **trabalhoVer.php?id=1** gostria que abrisse assim:

> www.site.com/87190-primeiro-teste

Não funciona:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /trabalhoVer.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Qual deverá ser o valor de `id`? Por quê não funciona? Qual é o erro gerado?

Comment: Valor `87190-primeiro-teste`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma, veja por favor se resolve:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ trabalhoVer.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Como solicitado no comentário, fiz o teste na porta 8080 assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080%{REQUEST_URI}  

    RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} ^8080$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ trabalhoVer.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Aqui deu certo. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estou usando localhost na porta 8080. Como faço para manter a porta de teste, e depois quando subir para o servidor remover? Quado carrego a página esta removendo a porta.

Comment: Tente assim:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080%{REQUEST_URI}  
 
 RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} ^8080$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ trabalhoVer.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>